# Flutter - how to check data perfectly uploaded/deleted or not to firebase database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

**Flutter - how to check data perfectly uploaded/deleted or not to firebase database?**

I want to check **(like addOnSuccessListener or addOnFailureListener in java)** data perfectly uploaded/deleted or not to firebase realtime database then show message to user then will go to next page.

code of uploading and deleting to firebase bellow:

**Data uploading code:**

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users').child(AuthUser().getUser().uid).set(user.toJson()).then((onValue){
        print('uploaded');
     });
```

**Data deleting code:**

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('users').child(AuthUser().getUser().uid).remove().then((onValue){
        print('deleted');
     });
```

**If you know please help me.**

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: like if one user have not permission to write, in this situation this user stuck here. even I can not message this user what happen.

again if network connection is poor then user stuck here. I can not message user that it's a connection problem or some thing else .@DougStevenson

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use a catch block on the returned promise to check for errors.  This is the way all dart futures work.

```
const ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
    .child('users')
    .child(AuthUser().getUser().uid)

ref.set(user.toJson())
.then(() { 
    // this is where success gets sent
})
.catchError((error) {
    // this is where permission denied errors get sent
});
```

See the documentation: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Answer (score 3):

Much simpler format with `async, await`
**Delete a User by ID:**

```
  void deleteUser(User user) async {
    await _userRef.child(user.id).remove().then((_) {
      print('User deleted.');
    });
  }
```

**Update a User:**

```
  void updateUser(User user) async {
    await _userRef.child(user.id).update({
      "name": "" + user.name,
      "age": "" + user.age,
      "email": "" + user.email,
      "mobile": "" + user.mobile,
    }).then((_) {
      print('User updated.');
    });
  }
```

- Here, `_userRef` is the `DatabaseReference`
- Don't forget to add `import 'dart:async';` at the top